# SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 11 while using JSON Parse for below string

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"ts": 2021-03-23T09:27:33.820Z,"ch":"STATUS","tag":"BIRTH","val":"1"}
```

Comment: the `ts` value should be in quotes as it is a string

Answer (score 3):

```
JSON.parse('{"ts": "2021-03-23T09:27:33.820Z","ch":"STATUS","tag":"BIRTH","val":"1"}')
```

2021-03-23T09:27:33.820Z is a string type as it contains numbers and characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your json is invalid.
Try adding quotes around 2021-03-23T09:27:33.820Z.
Like this:

```
{"ts": "2021-03-23T09:27:33.820Z","ch":"STATUS","tag":"BIRTH","val":"1"}
```